# Why is constant velocity of a body one-dimensional motion?

Tags: kinematics, terminology

If velocity of a particle is constant. It is in uniform motion. Why is it that it is a example of one-dimensional motion? It can still change its direction and have constant velocity.

By saying one-dimensional, we also mean to say it only moves in a straight line.

Comment: "It can still change its direction and have constant velocity." Can it? What does velocity mean?

Comment: Velocity is speed along with direction.Ohh.Since we write velocity.Therefore same direction.Thanks@jacob1729

Comment: One-dimensional does not mean moving along a *straight* path. It just means moving along a path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Velocity =displacement/ time $

If velocity is constant then you should interpret it as magnitude being constant as well as direction.

---

If it was constant speed then you could have said that direction can also change since speed corresponds to magnitude only.

Answer (score 1):

This is because, although the body might exist in three dimensions, or two, or even more, it can't possibly do anything that *needs* more than one dimension to describe. This is when you let the only dimension be the forwards-backwards dimension through which the body is moving. As such, it is referred to as "one-dimensional" motion because no extra dimensions are needed to figure anything out about the body through problem-solving, *provided that, as you say, it just maintains a constant velocity forever*.

You also assume something that is incorrect.

> It can still change its direction and have constant velocity.

If it were to change its direction, it would have changed its velocity. It would have the same *speed*, because it is moving through the same distance every unit time, but not the same *velocity*, because the way it is changing its position has changed. As such, changing its direction of motion is not an example of constant velocity, so the principle is upheld, *even though you do often require additional dimensions to describe motion that changes direction*.